# stompjs how to get status after sending message

Tags: javascript, java, spring, stomp, stompjs

i'm creating a chat application with spring boot websocket, STOMP and stompjs, here is my js code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sockjs-client/1.1.4/sockjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stomp.js/2.3.3/stomp.min.js"></script>
<script>
    //some code

    //send message
    stompClient.send("/app/chat.sendMessage", {}, JSON.stringify(chatMessage));
</script>
```

Backend code:

```
@MessageMapping("/chat.sendMessage")
public MessageDTO sendMessage(@Payload MessageDTO chatMessage) {
    //HERE
    if(!validatorService.validate(chatMessage)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("invalid");
    }
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/public", chatMessage);
    return chatMessage;
}
```

You can see I return the message. In js side is there anyway to receive this object, something like

```
stompClient.send("/app/chat.sendMessage", {}, JSON.stringify(chatMessage), callback);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a STOMP client sends a `MESSAGE` frame it usually won't get any response back from the broker at all. However, it *may* get back a [`RECEIPT` frame](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#RECEIPT) if the `MESSAGE` frame included the `receipt` header. You aren't setting this header so you shouldn't expect any response back from the broker.

If you wanted to get some kind of application-specific response then you would need to create a subsriber in your JavaScript app and the server-side app would need to send a message to wherever that consumer was listening. This is the classic [request/reply messaging pattern](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/RequestReply.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you provide me the code how to include the receipt and how to get response?